# Appending parameters in loop to CLI command

Tags: bash, loops, command-line-interface

I want to provide to python command multiple parameters stored in file.Example

```
command \
--param="var1" \
--param="var2" \
--param="var3 var3"
```

I am trying to: read them from file and store either in array or string. Of course, any optimal solutions are welcomed. However there is a problem with parsing it by python script while using loops/concatenating string and providing the variable to command.

```
stringparam=""
declare -a myarray=()

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
        myarray[$index]="--param=\"$line\""
        index=$(($index+1))
        stringparam+="--param=\"${line}\" "
    fi
done < "${input_file}"

echo ${myarray[@]}
echo "${prontos}"


# Execution
python_lib \
    "${force}" \
    --p1="${varp1}" \
    --p2="${varp2}" \
    --p3="${varp3}" \
    --p4="${varp4}" \
    --p5="${varp5}" \
    "$(for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do echo ${i}; done)" # approach 1
    "${stringparam}" # approach 2
```

Considering the file content's is:

moon - pancake

sun - star star

Output in the script:

1. How it should look like when provided manually i.e. --param="moon - pancake", etc.

   param = (u'moon - pancake', u'sun - star star')
2. How it looks like when done by adding loop or concatenated string:

   param = (u'"moon - pancake" --param="sun - star star" ',)

Prolly something to do with strings; many " declarations. What am I doing wrong and is there a better bash solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your second approach is more GNU/Bash-like, BUT you should NOT use quotes around it, otherwise the whole contents of $stringparam will be regarded as an unique parameter by your `python-lib` executable.

You should remove the quotes around it for - this time - all space characters be considered as parameters separator:

```
# Execution
python_lib \
    "${force}" \
    --p1="${varp1}" \
    --p2="${varp2}" \
    --p3="${varp3}" \
    --p4="${varp4}" \
    --p5="${varp5}" \
    $stringparam # approach 2
```

But to avoid issue with mixed single and double quotes, you should use simple quote, when building the $stringparam variable:

```
stringparam="$stringparam --param='${line}'"
```